# $.getJSON results into html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getjson, handlebars.js

I have read a few examples here however I am still a little stuck. 
I and getting a feed from an api that is formatted something like this

```
{
total:123,
id: "1234",
results: [
           {
           id: "1234",
           name: "bobs market",
           phone: "123-456-7890",
           othervalue: "33333333",
           onemore: "get this"
           },
           {
           id: "1235",
           name: "jans market",
           phone: "123-456-7899",
           othervalue: "33333353",
           onemore: "get this one"
           }
         ]
}
```

I am trying to use the $.getJSON feature to loop through each record and display each business inside a div with the id of #bizresults so the resulting html would look something like this

```
<div id="business">
      <h4><a href=#>Business Name</a></h4>
      <p id="phone">555-555-5555</p>
      <p id="adr">
      <span id="street-address">12 Main Street</span>
      <span id="locality">Sacramento</span>
      <span id="region">CA</span>
</div>
```

I seem to get the results in the script i can see them in the Chrome dev console however I cant seem to get the output to my div.

Taking the suggestion I looked @ Handlebars.js ** I am still just not quite there --

```
<script id="biz_template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

    <div id="businesses">
    {{#each jsonResult}}
    <a href=#><h4>{{name}}</a></h4>
    <p id="phone">{{phone}}</p>
    <p id="adr">
    <span id="street-address">{{address}}</span>
    <span id="locality">{{city}}</span>
    <span id="region">{{state}}</span>
    </p>
    {{/each}}
    </div>

  </script>




<script>
       var source = $("#biz_template").html();
       var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

var data = '{"totalCount":61,"impId":"17","jsonResult":[{"impId":"17","listingId":"94523","pageUrl":"/page/LA/new-orleans/ccs-coffee-house/17-94523.html","name":"CC's Coffee House","phone":"(504) 586-0278","address":"650 Poydras St","city":"New Orleans","state":"LA","latitude":"29.949339","longitude":"-90.070017"},{"impId":"17","listingId":"417428","pageUrl":"/page/LA/metairie/ccs-community-coffee-house/17-417428.html","name":"CC's Community Coffee House","phone":"(504) 831-1449","address":"701 Metairie Rd","city":"Metairie","state":"LA","latitude":"29.98763","longitude":"-90.130528"},{"impId":"17","listingId":"228835","pageUrl":"/page/LA/new-orleans/ccs-community-coffee-house/17-228835.html","name":"Cc's Community Coffee House","phone":"(504) 566-1863","address":"228 St Charles Av","city":"New Orleans","state":"LA","latitude":"29.951952","longitude":"-90.069885"}]}';

$("#biz").html(template(data));
 </script>
```

Any thoughts?

I do have div with the id of biz in the HTML

Comment: Please post the JavaScript code. That's what matters here...

Comment: You would do that like this -> http://jsbin.com/idefix/1/edit

Comment: if you want to do it once use the example given by adeneo. If you want to do this kind of thing many times mustache would help greatly http://mustache.github.com/

Comment: use a templating engine (any from underscore to handlebars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a plugin with `$.getJSON` and handlebars, this is just parts of it and basically all you need. I can post the whole plugin if you want to.

dont forget to reference the file or url to handlebars

```
<script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

var container = $('#tweets'),
    template: $('#tweets-template').html()

$.getJSON(this.url, function(data) {
                    var tweets = $.map(data.results, function(tweet) {
                        return {
                            author: tweet.from_user,
                            tweet: tweet.text,
                            thumb: tweet.profile_image_url,
                            url: 'http://twitter.com/' + tweet.from_user + '/status/' + tweet.id_str
                        };
                    });

                    var templateHandlebars = Handlebars.compile(template);
                    container.append(templateHandlebars(tweets));
});


//this is the html and the template
<ul id="tweets">
        <script id="tweets-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            {{#each this}}
                <li>
                    <img src={{thumb}} alt={{author}} />
                    <p><a href={{url}}>{{tweet}}</a></p>
                </li>
            {{/each}}
        </script>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The task here is to build up markup in the getJSON success function.  You can do that either by concatinating strings or by using a templating system like handlebars, JsRender, underscore, etc.  If you're looking for two-way binding, look to Angular or Knockout.

Comment: Ok - in looking at this handlebars looks interesting however I have never used it - I will poke around some - but any guidence there would help me get moving forward -